# Chrome extension: How to modify elements created from an Ajax request in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension for this page http://jisho.org/kanji/radicals/ and I've got a problem.

The extension should modify the elements containing "kanji" found in the `#found_kanji` `div`, but those elements are not there when the page loads, rather, they are created after the user clicks a "radical"(a part of a kanji) which triggers an Ajax query that loads the kanji from the website database.

How can I modify those elements?

From what I've looked up, DOM manipulation events are now deprecated, so I can't watch for when the elements are created. I could try to replace the website javascript with a local version by using the webRequests API, I thought it would be ugly but it could work, but then I realized I have no way to communicate from a webpage script to a content script or the extension itself. Anyone got ideas?

Comment: How about an extension that requires a manual interaction to be activated? If the data is not available once the page is loaded and the user is interested in the Kanji modifications introduced by your extension, let him click somewhere.

Comment: @theMarceloR that sounds inconvenient, I'd rather do this in the most automated way possible. Specially since the modification I want to do is just highlighting certain kanji based on data stored in the extension somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `MutationObserver` to listen for DOM changes within a particular div, and perform your modifications whenever new elements are added to the div:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if(mutation.addedNodes.length){
        var addedNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(mutation.addedNodes);
        addedNodes.forEach(function(node){
            if(node.className == 'something'){
                // do stuff
            }
        });
    }
  });    
});

observer.observe(document.getElementById('found_kanji'), { subtree: true, childList: true, characterData: true });
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QVd7m/)

Comment: Thanks! I heard about mutation events getting deprecated but I didn't know it was replaced by a different event handler. Your solution worked perfectly :D